# Top Navigation Menu does not format well in IE 7.0 but is fine all other browsers and versions of IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I am working on a webiste http://www.kerin.net/who.cfm but its top menu is not format well in IE7.0 but it well in all ather browser . 
Can anybody please suggest me some ways to rectify this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you have a table based layout. No wonder if any one will even try to help you. Table based layout is a big "NO NO" in modern web development. Not that I am against it.

To fix the issues, do as follows.

```
div.menu
{
width: 50px; /*you can have any width you like here */
}
```

It is not clear from you question that how are you testing in IE7. I tested it using the IE7 mode in IE9 from the web development toolbar and fixes the issue. The broken layout of the top menu is fixed and they sit along each other, same as in IE9 on windows 7.

If you are going to ask any further question as to why it is so or if it is a bug, I honestly dont't know. Your code is so messed up, it will take quite some time to dig in there. The same results can be achived using simpler markup. nav element in HTML5 and div element with nested ul and li elements in HTML/XHTML lower than 5. You current code goes like

```
div.sidemenu1 > div.menu > ul > li > div.nav-text > ................ and so on
```

A bloody management nightmare. You really should try to simplify your markup.

Comment: You are welcome. If it fixed your issue and answered the question, you are requested to mark the answer as accepted.